# How do I have my flutter code wait for a function to complete before continuing?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am having problems finding out a way to have my code wait for a function to complete before continuing on. The reason for this is because I need the function to retrieve the current user from firebase first, before then going on to use this value and decide which screen to show next.

The way I intend for the code to work is to check if there is already a user signed in. If there is then perform another check to see whether or not information exists for that user - if it does then return the home screen and if it doesnt return the user information screen. If there is no user currently signed in then the Authenticate screen should show.

```
class SignedInState extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   final user = _getCurrentUser();

    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
     final snapShot = checkifDocumentExists(user);
      if (snapShot == null) {
      return UserInformation();
      } else {
      return Home();
    }
    }
  }
}
```

```
Future _getCurrentUser() async {
   final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   print(user);
   print(user.toString());
   return user;
    }
```

This is my first time posting here so just let me know if you need more details etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same problem just yesterday. I found the solution to use `final user = Provider.of<User>(context);` instead. So if you made a User object after the authentication you might can use it too.

Answer (score 0):

_getCurrentUser cannot be in the build method. In fact, it is forbidden to insert or call any method within the build method, according to the documentation, build methods should only receive widgets.

To do this, you must call the function in the initState method:

```
class SignedInState extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignedInStateState createState() => _SignedInStateState();
}

class _SignedInStateState extends State<SignedInState> {
  var user; // made user acessible to all class
  bool hasData = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // call method when build is done
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _getCurrentUser());
  }

  Future _getCurrentUser() async {
    user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      hasData = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!hasData) {
      return Container();
    } else if (user == null && hasData) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      final snapShot = checkifDocumentExists(user);
      if (snapShot == null) {
        return UserInformation();
      } else {
        return Home();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Calling methods from the build method is not "forbidden". It can be discouraged depending on the purpose of the method in question.